# Black Render output

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, video

Morning everyone,

I am totally new to Blender, and just wanted to use a template for a YouTube intro.

The template i use/want to use can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz2JIbjYQociQ29nNU9ZNkdNbHc/view).

The things i have changed were the resulotion to 1920*1080, the audio bitrate to 256(MP3), lossless output, and of course the shown text and where the file should be after the rendering is done.

The problem is (and i im pretty sure it would be easy to put it right if i knew how to) that the final result is just completely black with the sound.

I have no idea how to "fix" this and it would be nice, if someone could help me. :)

Comment: It works just fine for me, try to open the original file again, and make a render, see if that works. The only other thing i can think of is that you are using a player that doesnt support the codex you used for exporting. Try using a different player, or a different codex.

EDIT: Also, i dont think Youtube supports 256br at all, and during upload will convert it anyway. But i am not 100% on that, it might have changed over time.

Comment: I can do what i want, the video at the end is completely black.

Comment: Isnt that the black that is usually used to fade into the next part of the video? So cutting it out isnt a sollution?

Comment: I think i wrote something wrong xD . I mean the whole video is just completely black.

Comment: Weird, idk what is going wrong, everything works peachy for me. So i think i cant really help.